# Ghost Typing into Browser

Tags: bots, typing

I'm working on a Chat Bot that needs to do some automatic "ghost" typing into your web browser (or other software). The target platform is Mac OSX, but there might be a need for a port to other OS's in the future. What needs to be accomplished is to take over the user's keyboard and "ghost" type for them.

What programming language would suit this project best? If you are also knowledgable in this topic, please help steer me in the right direction. Cheers.

Comment: Did you already stumbled over javascript? Also target platform and browser seems to be in contradiction.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't make myself clear. The idea is that the software would take over your keyboard and type for you. It shouldn't be limited to only your web browser. Unfortunately, this is a very new topic for me and I could use a little nudge in the right direction. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your target OS is a Mac OSX you should look to develop your software with Objective-C and Cocoa

More information: http://developer.apple.com/technologies/mac/cocoa.html

However if you are a C/C++ developer you can develop 32-bit OSX software with Carbon, this would make it easier to port if you decide to at a later date.

More information: http://developer.apple.com/carbon/